# Has dirty pipe vulnerability been fixed in ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04

I noticed a new problem with Linux called "dirty pipe". Has this been fixed? I have Linux version 5.13.0. Thanks

Comment: Yes it's been fixed when your system has updated the latest security patches and has rebooted.

Comment: When asking about a vulnerability, it's best to refer to a specific CVE instead of a "name" you read somewhere. Name confusion might get you an inaccurate or misleading answer. And once you have a CVE, the first place you should check is the Ubuntu Security Team's CVE tracker.